# Read SPSS Viewer files (.spv) with Python

Tags: python, spss

There seems to be a million questions on reading SPSS .sav files via Python but nothing on reading SPSS .**spv** files, aka Viewer Files. See image below, highlighted in yellow.

My aim is to read the information within it (usually frequencies, tables, charts etc) and do something fun with it. I know you can export the same information in excel but I want to know if I can work directly with the .spv file.

Is this possible?

[image]